# Is $v$ necessarily an eigenvector of the linear map $\varphi\circ\varphi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of a linear map $\varphi:V\rightarrow V$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Prove that $v$ is also an eigenvector of $\varphi^2=\varphi\circ\varphi$.

Attempt: Since $v$ is an eigenvector we have $\varphi(v)=\lambda v$ and so $\varphi(\varphi(v))=\varphi(\lambda v)$. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: $\varphi$ is a **linear** map

Comment: $\varphi(\lambda v)=\lambda\varphi(v)=\dots$

Comment: @StephenDonovan So we have that $\varphi(\varphi(v))=\lambda^2v$. How does this prove the claim though?

Comment: What would it mean for $v$ to be an eigenvector of $\varphi \circ \varphi$?

Comment: Another hint in case you were confused: note that the problem does not say that the associated eigenvalue must still be $\lambda.$ If you are using $\lambda$ to represent the eigenvalue of $v$ associated with $\varphi \circ \varphi$ then you're using the same symbol to denote two different values: consider using something like $k$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. $\varphi^2(v)=\varphi(\varphi(v))=\varphi(\lambda v)= \lambda \varphi( v)=\lambda \lambda v=\lambda^2 v$. The eigenvalue is $\lambda^2$